# Replace a specific line in a file using Ruby

Tags: ruby, line, overwrite

I have a text file (a.txt) that looks like the following.

```
open
close
open
open
close
open
```

I need to find a way to replace the 3rd line with "close".  I did some search and most method involve searching for the line than replace it.  Can't really do it here since I don't want to turn all the "open" to "close".

Essentially (for this case) I'm looking for a write version of IO.readlines("./a.txt") [2].

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about something like:

```
lines = File.readlines('file')
lines[2] = 'close' << $/
File.open('file', 'w') { |f| f.write(lines.join) }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
str = <<-_
my
dog
has
fleas
_

FNameIn  = 'in'
FNameOut = 'out'
```

First, let's write `str` to `FNameIn`:

```
File.write(FNameIn, str)
  #=> 17
```

Here are a couple of ways to replace the third line of `FNameIn` with "had" when writing the contents of `FNameIn` to `FNameOut`.

**#1 Read a line, write a line**

If the file is large, you should read from the input file and write to the output file one line at a time, rather than keeping large strings or arrays of strings in memory.

```
fout = File.open(FNameOut, "w")
File.foreach(FNameIn).with_index { |s,i| fout.puts(i==2 ? "had" : s) }
fout.close
```

Let's check that `FNameOut` was written correctly:

```
puts File.read(FNameOut)
my
dog
had
fleas
```

Note that [IO#puts](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/IO.html#method-i-puts) writes a record separator if the string does not already end with a record separator.<sup>1</sup>. Also, if `fout.close` is omitted `FNameOut` is closed when `fout` goes out of scope.

**#2 Use a regex**

```
r = /
    (?:[^\n]*\n) # Match a line in a non-capture group
    {2}          # Perform the above operation twice
    \K           # Discard all matches so far
    [^\n]+       # Match next line up to the newline
    /x           # Free-spacing regex definition mode

File.write(FNameOut, File.read(FNameIn).sub(r,"had"))

puts File.read(FNameOut)
my
dog
had
fleas
```

<sup>1 `File.superclass #=> IO`, so `IO`'s methods are inherited by `File`.</sup>